# Capture the Search text and pass it in a URL when clicked on Submit

Tags: php

I just cant get around this simple requirement. I am new to PHP and need help.

I need to capture the value in a Search Box and then pass it in the URL which opens in a new tab when hit on Submit.

What am I missing here..it seems like I am missing a lot of things for this to work..

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $example = $_post['searchon'];
    echo '<a target = '_blank' href=http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=.$example.&tag=orientmarketi-21></a>';
 }
?>  

  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="search" name="searchon" id="searchon" />
    <input type="submit" name ="submit" />
        </form>
```

Comment: there's no text between your `a` tags so nothing will show. Try `<a target = '_blank' href=http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=.$example.&tag=orientmarketi-21>{PLACEHOLDER}</a>`. Note the `{PLACEHOLDER}` value

Answer (score 0):

try this code instead of your one:

```
<form action="http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1" method="get" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="search-alias=aps" />
<input type="hidden" name="tag" value="orientmarketi-21" />
<input type="text" name="field-keywords"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to create two tabs and open two different URLs in a similar way? I actually need two to be working this way..

Comment: @user2918177 do you mean open two different tabs by clicking single button?

Comment: @user2918177 no, this approach will not work, you need to use javascript and onsubmit handler

Comment: Hmm..Could you please help me with that approach..I need to get this done urgently

Comment: I cannot help you in this case